# Как удалить копии строк без создания/модификации таблиц и отсутствии primary key?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с локациями где надо оставить 1 уникальную запись. Как удалить копии строк без ключа, модификации или создания таблиц?

Запросом ниже получилось удалить все копии, но хотелось бы 1 запись оставлять для каждой страны и её города. Как это исправить?

```
DELETE base from locations AS base
JOIN (SELECT * FROM locations
GROUP BY country, city
HAVING COUNT(city) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(city) DESC) AS newT
WHERE newT.country = base.country
AND newT.city = base.city;
```

Comment: primary key не объявлен, но есть столбец с уникальными данными или строки в `locations` абсолютно идентичны?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Строки могут быть `aw;name`, `aw;name2`, `aw;name`. Столбца `id` нет

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE t1
FROM locations t1
JOIN locations t2 USING (country, city)
WHERE t1.id > t2.id
```

Запрос удалит все дубликаты по `(country, city)`, оставив в каждой группе только одну запись - с наименьшим `id`.

Ну и сразу создайте уникальный индекс по указанной группе полей - чтобы такие дубликаты не появлялись в будущем.

---

> колонки id или primary key не существует – Pashok

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_remove_duplicates ()
BEGIN
  REPEAT
    WITH cte AS ( 
      SELECT country, city
      FROM locations 
      GROUP BY 1, 2
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      LIMIT 1 
      )
    DELETE 
    FROM locations 
    WHERE (country, city) IN (
      SELECT country, city
      FROM cte
      ) 
    LIMIT 1;
  UNTIL NOT ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
END
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/KqcVdBMu)

Удаление выполняется по одной записи, так что наберитесь терпения.

Comment: Как я и говорил в вопросе, колонки `id` или `primary key` не существует

Comment: @Pashok Гм... а есть хоть что-то, какая-то комбинация полей, которая уникальна для каждой записи?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению не знаком со спецификой mysql. В ms sql это можно было сделать двумя способами:

1. Сделать курсором цикл по выборке из таблицы с сортировкой по `country` и `city`. В цикле сохранять значения этих столбцов в дублирующие переменные и на следующей итерации сравнивать значения из текущей строки и прошлой (сохранённые в переменные). Если совпадают, удалять текущую строку курсора.
2. При помощи `ROW_NUMBER` пронумеровать все дубликаты, и удалить те, у которых номер больше единицы:

```
DELETE FROM locations
WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY country, city ORDER BY country) > 1
```

Сортировка в ORDER BY нам не важна, но в MS SQL она обязательная

Comment: *При помощи ROW_NUMBER пронумеровать все дубликаты* MySQL так не умеет. Пока во всяком случае. А ROW_NUMBER во WHERE вообще никто не умеет.